# Разбивка и запись ассоциативного массива в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, база-данных

В базе данных есть таблица `table` с 4 колонками:

```
day | active | start_time | end_time
```

Также есть массив ассоциативного типа:

```
$monday = ["day" => "Понедельник", "active" => "1", "start_time" => "08:00", "end_time" => "12:00"];
```

Пытаюсь записать содержимое массива в базу данных с разбивкой по ячейкам:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (day, active, start_time, end_time) VALUES (" . $monday["day"] . ", " . $monday["active"] . ", " . $monday["start_time"] . ", " . $monday["end_time"] . ")";
```

Но в таблицу в базе данных ничего не записывается. Подскажите, как мне записать содержимое массива с разбивкой по ячейкам, чтобы таблица была следующего вида:

```
day         | active | start_time | end_time
Понедельник | 1      | 08:00      | 12:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в кавычках, в которые Вам нужно было обернуть данные строкового и временного типа.

Вот правильный запрос:

> INSERT INTO table (day, active, start_time, end_time) VALUES ('Понедельник', 1, '08:00', '12:00')

А вот код, его формирующий:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO table (day, active, start_time, end_time) VALUES ('%s', %s, '%s', '%s')", $monday['day'], $monday['active'], $monday['start_time'], $monday['end_time']);
```

P.S. А для того, чтобы не путаться в кавычках при формировании SQL кода, я рекомендую использовать функцию [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php).